# How to test Pulse Code Modulated sound signal?

Tags: mems-microphone, pcm

I'm trying to perform a PDM to PCM conversion. The PDM signal is coming from MEMS microphone.

There are different decimation approaches like FIR, CIC, cascade Half Band(HB) filters and so on. How successful is the PCM signal I got and how accurate is the conversion? How can I measure this?

What comes to my mind is to excite the microphone with a sinus tone and time-domain graph, recording the PCM signal and playing it as sound (this may be relative) or examine the frequency response.

Comment: You may get more responses if you focus your question.

Comment: graphs are rarely the right way to get a single quantifiable entity, i.e. a single number. As always, you'll need to derive the "quality indicator" from your use case!

Comment: What are your goals for THD dynamic range and SNR?  Is there some reason you don’t want to use ADAU7112

Comment: I use FPGA so i prefer decimate the signal inside it. İ'm doing voice recorder and parameters are not specified yet now. Should i look THD and SNR under excitation of sound tone?